# Multitouch with gestures in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In this gesture multi-point control [demo](https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/compose/gestures?hl=zh-cn#multitouch), it should be zooming and rotating with two fingers, but I found that one finger can be dragged in the test.
I want to drag with two fingers, how can I modify it?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TransformableSample() {
    // set up all transformation states
    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, offsetChange, rotationChange ->
        scale *= zoomChange
        rotation += rotationChange
        offset += offsetChange
    }
    Box(
        Modifier
            // apply other transformations like rotation and zoom
            // on the pizza slice emoji
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale,
                scaleY = scale,
                rotationZ = rotation,
                translationX = offset.x,
                translationY = offset.y
            )
            // add transformable to listen to multitouch transformation events
            // after offset
            .transformable(state = state)
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .fillMaxSize()
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I updated the code, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Modifier.transformable` doesn't have much customization options, you can copy source code file to your project and replace

```
val panChange = event.calculatePan()
```

With

```
val panChange = if (event.changes.count() > 1) event.calculatePan() else Offset.Zero
```

Comment: I used your method and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Modifier as

```
Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        awaitEachGesture {
            // Wait for at least one pointer to press down
            awaitFirstDown()

            do {

                val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                // You can set this as required
                 if(event.changes.size==2){
                     offset = event.calculatePan()
                     // zoom
                     event.calculateZoom()
                     // rotation
                     event.calculateRotation()
                 }

                // This is for preventing other gestures consuming events
                // prevent scrolling or other continuous gestures
                event.changes.forEach { pointerInputChange: PointerInputChange ->
                    pointerInputChange.consume()
                }
            } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
        }
    }
```

I also wrote a library that returns transform values with start, move, and end callbacks and number of pointer down that you can also use

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Extended-Gestures

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
  detectTransformGestures(
    onGestureStart = {
      transformDetailText = "GESTURE START"
    },
    onGesture = { gestureCentroid: Offset,
                  gesturePan: Offset,
                  gestureZoom: Float,
                  gestureRotate: Float,
                  mainPointerInputChange: PointerInputChange,
                  pointerList: List<PointerInputChange> ->
     
    },
    onGestureEnd = {
      borderColor = Color.LightGray
      transformDetailText = "GESTURE END"
    }
  )
}
```

Or this one that checks number of pointers and prequsite condition before returning zoom, rotate, drag and so on

```
Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectPointerTransformGestures(
            numberOfPointers = 1,
            requisite = PointerRequisite.GreaterThan,
          onGestureStart = {
            transformDetailText = "GESTURE START"
          },
            onGesture = { gestureCentroid: Offset,
                          gesturePan: Offset,
                          gestureZoom: Float,
                          gestureRotate: Float,
                          numberOfPointers: Int ->

            },
            onGestureEnd = {
                transformDetailText = "GESTURE END"
            }
        )
    }
```